How to quit full-screen application?
I have a virtual Ubuntu system which automatically launches an application in full screen mode,  but the application hangs immediately and becomes unresponsive. All I see is a black screen.
How can I quit the application to be able to try to do something in the system, like reinstalling the application?

When you say virtual, do you mean you have installed it on a virtual machine? Which one? How was it set up? Do you have snapshots? Can you switch to a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or other F keys)?

On my rig Ctrl+Alt+F1 gives you a login prompt. Ctrl+Alt+F3{4,5,6 etc} give a terminal and Ctrl+Alt+F2 goes back to to your original screen. From a terminal 'ps -ea' will show you all the processes running with their process number. Identify the one one you wish to terminate then 'kill -9 {proc-number}' Possibly with elevated privileges - ie starting with 'sudo' but you have to have been given elevated privileges.

You could go into recovery mode at the grub screen and uninstall the offending program.
